# Progress 4GL - need to select Excel worksheet by name

Tags: excel, progress-4gl

Through a Progress 4GL program, I am trying to select a specific worksheet in the workbook.  The worksheet name I am trying to select is called "Budget".  Any ideas on how I can select this by name.  Provide sample code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it but this should work:

```
CREATE "Excel.Application" chExcelApplication.

chWorkSheet = chExcelApplication:Sheets("SheetName")
```